# Redirect to profile page after login AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, function, redirect, authentication

I am currently working on an Angular project for school for which I need to change the current webpage if there's been a successful login.
The login part finally is working, but now I'm a bit lost as to how I'm supposed to redirect the user to their page if they've successfully logged in.

My login function detects a success message and uses that as an argument for the function from which I want to redirect the user (The error message redirection I'll get to later):

```
redirect(message) {
    if (message == "Logged in."){
      console.log("success")
      $window.location.href = '/user.html';
    }
    if (message == "Password incorrect, please try again"){

    }
    if (message == "No user registered with this e-mail"){

    }
  }
```

This is what I currently have, inspired by some other answers on here. It's not working because the $window variable is undefined, I have tried injecting it into the function but that didn't work either. All the answers I've seen somehow implemented this through a controller, but I finally have the login working without using controllers so I'd rather solve it this way (if that's possible) than to now implement my whole program differently.
I am very new to angular if that wasn't clear already so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `window.location` or `window.location.href`.

Think of `$window` as the 'angularJS version" of the global `window` object.

You don't need to use it, but it makes mocking and unit testing easier.